# PostgreSQL/PostGIS error "pseudo-type record"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql-view

I've got, in PostgreSQL/PostGIS,

```
create table datos (
gbifID int primary key,
orden varchar (50),
eventDate varchar (50),
geom geometry);
```

When I run

```
select distinct (geom,eventdate), geom
from datos
where orden='x';
```

it works OK. However,

```
create view esfuerzo as 
select distinct (geom,eventdate), geom
from datos
where orden='x';
```

returns 
ERROR:  column "row" has pseudo-type record
Estado SQL: 42P16. How can I create such a view?

Comment: The correct syntax is `SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom, eventdate) geom, eventdate FROM datos WHERE orden='x'`. By omitting on, Postgres thinks you are looking for a composite type, rather than essentially just a GROUP BY geom, evendate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom, eventdate) geom, eventdate FROM datos WHERE orden='x'. By omitting on, Postgres thinks you are looking for a composite type, rather than essentially just a GROUP BY geom, evendate. – John Powell Jul 3 at 15:28

Comment: This is exactly the right solution for me. Have my solitary upvote

Answer (score 3):

As @IanTurton pointed out, enclosing (multiple) column names in parenthesis will [invoke a cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) to `RECORD`.

Simply run

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW esfuerzo AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
         eventdate,
         geom
  FROM   datos
  WHERE  orden = 'x'
;
```

**or possibly better**, the equivalent

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW esfuerzo AS
  SELECT geom
  FROM   datos
  WHERE  orden = 'x'
  GROUP BY
         eventdate, geom
;
```

where you can choose the columns to select from the list passed to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a [pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-pseudo.html) as a column type. Since `geom` and `eventdate` are different types I suspect you get a sort of undefined type in the results. You may be able to cast it to something specific or could maybe try:

```
create view esfuerzo as 
select distinct (st_astext(geom),eventdate), geom
from datos
where orden='x';
```

to make the result a `varchar`.

Comment: Same error result with st_astext

Comment: Actually, I only need that "distinct (geom,eventdate)" as a filter, not the actual results. Perhaps it could be specified somehow within the WHERE conditions?

Comment: if you *really* need a composite type in a *View* you can cast the implicit record to a type both values can safely be cast to. e.g. `TEXT`: `CREATE VIEW esfuerzo AS SELECT (geom, eventdate)::TEXT ...` (which will be translated into `... ROW(geom, eventdate)::TEXT as "row" ...`). Or, better, create a specific type to be able to keep the column types.

Comment: I suspect the OP wasn't actually looking for a composite type but simply a DISTINCT ON (x,y) type query. The question is lacking a certain amount of detail, it is true.